# How to check an array of an array for an object

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to check if a two-dimensional array contains an object, how would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use nested loops. Suppose you have an array of arrays of `Integer`, and you want to check if a specific number is inside the array:

```
static boolean contains(Integer[][] array, Integer wantedInt) {
    // For each sub-array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // For each element in the sub-array
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            // If the element is the wanted one
            if (array[i][j].equals(wantedInt)) {
                // We've found it
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // We didn't find the wanted number
    return false;
}
```

You could use the same logic to search for any object type by using generics:

```
static <T> boolean contains(T[][] array, T wantedObj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (array[i][j].equals(wantedObj)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Object objects[][] = new Object[100][];
 Object objectToLocate = null;
     outerloop:
     for (Object[] object : objects) {
        for (Object o : objects) {
            if (o == objectToLocate) {
                System.out.println("Found it!");
                break outerloop;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for objects:

```
    Object[][] twoDArray = new Object[x][y];

    // Fill array

    for (int i = 0; i < twoDArray.length; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[i].length; ++j)
        {
            if (twoDArray[i][j].equals(someObject))
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
```